# WooCommerce : Automatically generate a coupon if the customer is a VIP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

I'd like to generate a coupon if a person has spent over $750.

I was thinking that I could display the coupon on the checkout page, or perhaps email. The coupon would have a life of 12 months from the date of issue.

I have found some very useful code which I have assembled into something which I believe should work, but it doesn't

I'd be very grateful for a pointer on where I might be going wrong.

---

First I want to see if the customer has spent over $750
if they do extract user id and Order ID and send to coupon code generation

```php
// Function to work out if a customer is a VIP
function ch_cust_is_a_vip()
{
   if (ch_get_customer_spend() > 750)
   {
    $ch_order = wc_get_order( $order_id );       // get current order_id
    $ch_user = get_current_user_id();            // Current user ID

    coupon_code_generation( $ch_order, $ch_user );
   }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form_cart_notices', 'ch_cust_is_a_vip', 20, 2 );  // woocommerce_before_checkout_form_cart_notices
```

---

Function to calculate customer spend

```php
// function to return total customer spend
function ch_get_customer_spend()
{
  global $wpdb;

 $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Current user ID

 $user_purchases_total_sum = $wpdb->get_var( "
   SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
   WHERE p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
   AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_order_total' AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
   AND pm2.meta_value LIKE $user_id " );

 return $user_purchases_total_sum;
}
```

---

And the coupon code generation , I've found this ad just added the 12 month expire date.

```php
  // Utility function that check if coupon exist
  function does_coupon_exist( $coupon_code ) 
  {
     global $wpdb;

     $value = $wpdb->get_var( "
       SELECT ID
       FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
       WHERE post_type = 'shop_coupon'
       AND post_name = '".strtolower($coupon_code)."'
       AND post_status = 'publish'; ");

   return $value > 0 ? true : false;
 }

////////////////////////////////////
// custom coupon generation 
///////////////////////////////////

  function coupon_code_generation( $order_id, $i )
  {
   $coupon_code = $order_id."".$i; // Coupon Code

   // Check that coupon code not exists
   if( ! does_coupon_exist( $coupon_code ) ) 
  {

    // Get a new instance of the WC_Coupon object
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon();

    // Get the instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    ## --- Coupon settings --- ##
    $discount_type  = 'percent'; // set the dicount Type
    $coupon_amount  = '30'; // set the discount Amount
    $customer_email = array( $order->get_billing_email() ); // Customer billing email
    $product_categories_names = array('skincare');
    $date_expires = strtotime("+ 12 Months"); // put an expiry date 12 months from today 

    // Convert to term IDs
    $term_ids = array();
    foreach( $product_categories_names as $term_name ) 
    {
        if ( term_exists( $term_name, 'product_cat' ) )
            $term_ids[] = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, 'product_cat' )->term_id;
    }

    ## --- Coupon settings --- ##

    // Set the necessary coupon data
    $coupon->set_code( $coupon_code );
    $coupon->set_discount_type( $discount_type );
    $coupon->set_amount( $coupon_amount );

    if( is_array($term_ids) && sizeof($term_ids) > 0 )
        $coupon->set_product_categories( $term_ids );

    $coupon->set_email_restrictions( $customer_email );
    $coupon->set_individual_use( true );
    $coupon->set_usage_limit( 1 );
    $coupon->set_usage_limit_per_user( 1 );
    $coupon->set_limit_usage_to_x_items( 1 );
    $coupon->set_date_expires( date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date_expires) ) );

    // Save the data
    $post_id = $coupon->save();
 }

  echo isset($post_id) && $post_id > 0 ? sprintf(
    '<div class="couponCode"><strong>%s <code>%s</code></strong>.<hr></div>',
    __("Your Coupon Code for your next purchase is", "woocommerce"), $coupon_code
  ) : __("Sorry, a coupon code already exist.", "woocommerce");
}
```

---

I do sometimes see an error with  ' `$customer_email = array( $order->get_billing_email() );` // Customer billing email' but not always

Comment: Have you checked [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wt-smart-coupons-for-woocommerce/)

Comment: To be clear: you mean a total from $750, considering all orders from that customer OR for the current order of which the total is more than $750

Comment: HI Yes, I am testing for a condition in that a customer has previously spent at least $750. thanks

Comment: hi Mujuonly - thanks for that, I am aware that there are plugins for this sort of thing, but i'd prefer to have something that just meets the requirement, plugins usually have lots of other functions which I probably don't need.

Comment: $user = get_user_by('id', $i); and  $user->user_email will. get you the email id . The custom email will be the apt one right?

Comment: @KeithHill [Get total spent by customer](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_customer_total_spent/)

Comment: @KeithHill Method I would use. **1)** Use the email sent to a customer when the order is complete. **2)** Before the coupon code is added to that e-mail, check whether it already exists (this by generating a specific name for a coupon for each customer) and whether the customer has already bought for more than 750. **3)** 
If the coupon does not exist yet, and the condition of 750 is met. Create the coupon and add the couponcode to the email.

Comment: @KeithHill - which one is failing for you?

Comment: Hi @mujuonly , the error I see relates to ' $customer_email = array( $order->get_billing_email() ); // Customer billing email'    .                                                                                      
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_billing_email() on bool in /home/clairehi/staging/1/wp-content/themes/halena-child/functions.php:1193

Comment: if(!is_object($order)){ return; } -- add this line after     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

Comment: Hi @7uc1f3r and mujuonly thanks for the help, with customer spend and your suggestion. I think the issue is simply that I am using '$order_id' but i've not actually set it to the current order, so when I reference 'get_billing_email()' it throwing an error as I'm not referencing an order. I am assuming that the order ID get set once somebody has added something to their cart.